# Same origin issue (file upload)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

The client is on domain `foo.com` and needs to upload (send POST XMLHttpRequest) to `upload.foo.com`.

This is restricted because of the same origin policy.
However, the work around that I managed to come up with is, to dynamically create `iframe` on `foo.com` opening `upload.foo.com` and append the JavaScript code which executes the POST request from `upload.foo.com` like this:
`iframe.onLoad` [..]

```
(a=(b=doc)
.createElement('script'))
.src='http://foo.com/upload.php?'+Math.random(),
b.body.appendChild(a);
void(0);
```

Now, to me this seems redundant: if the later is possible, my logic tells me that the former should be possible as well. Is it?

-- update

I have just noticed that there is file on the sub domain containing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
<allow-access-from domain="*.foo.com" secure="false" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Can I use it somehow to my advantage?

Comment: Did you got this running? Because I don't think you can manipulate iframes from other domains also.

Comment: The `iframe` concept works, yes. I have been using it for few days now.

Comment: is it possible to do it like this. on foo.com load iframe src bar.foo.com; append a callback that would call a function in the parent page (I do have rights to modify iframe's content) and from that callback function make XMLHttpRequest as though from that iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is not sensitive to document.domain because the object requires mutual opt-in for security reasons, and XHR has no way of knowing what the target might want the document.domain value to be set to. In order for SiteA to interact with the DOM of a site on SiteB, both sites must share a common private domain suffix, and both must opt-in to the communication by setting document.domain to their common suffix.

Your cross-domain policy file doesn't actually make a lot of sense (as it opts-in everything, and then a subset of everything) but it's used for Flash, not XHR (which uses CORS).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to simplify this, but if it seems inelegant to you, there are simpler ways to use cross-origin JS.

Indeed, this is almost exactly what jQuery does if you try to send a request using jsonp. [Wikipedia for JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
(Along with several other ways to bypass the same-origin restriction)

I don't know if this is what you're asking about, but in the name of maintainability, I would advise that you use the [jQuery approach](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

You need to set **dataType: 'jsonp'** and you're all set. 
You can optionally set the parameter "callback=?"(look at the docs).